# Excel to SQL Security

Tags: sql, excel, vba, security, encryption

I use the VBA script below in an Excel module to allow a connection to a SQL server with a preprogramed username and password. The connection runs a basic select query however I need to hide or encrypt the password. The only methods I can think of are hiding the password in another sheet, locking the VBA or to call a text file from a shared drive that contains the password. However these methods still seem unsecure. Does anyone know of a better security method that can be implemented within the excel VBA?

Sub ConnectSqlServer()

```
Dim txt As String
txt = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value
If txt Like "*[A-Z]*" Or txt Like "*[;]*" Or txt Like "*[""]*" Then
    a = MsgBox("Invalid" & vbNewLine & "Try again", okonly + vbCritical, "SECURITY WARNING")
Exit Sub

Else

End If

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String

sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=TESTSQLSERVER2012;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=MASTER;" & _
              "User ID=LOGINREADUSER;" & _
              "Password=123456789;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open sConnString
conn.CommandTimeout = 0

Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT [ACCOUNT],[NAME].[DOB]" & _
        "from [MASTER].[dbo].[CUSTOMER]" & _
        ";")

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If

If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Even then the VBA could be hacked.  Can you add a non-password or guest user with access to a view only, which is your SQL?

Comment: Either prompt the user for UserId and Password per instance or get your SQL server to authenticate with Windows account. All else is unsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can't hardcode the password and have it be safe, no matter what you do with it. There are always ways to extract the password from the code.

In response to that, either have a log-in prompt or use inbuilt windows-auth for SQL server.